# Retrieve records that have been timestamp updated since last accessed / read

Tags: php, mysql

The following is a simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve. I just can't figure it out.

I have two tables:

```
Table 1: messages
id | timestamp | message
------------------------
1 | 2014-01-20 09:00:00 | Hello I'm a message
2 | 2014-01-20 09:00:00 | Second message for you
3 | 2014-01-27 11:00:00 | This message has been updated
4 | 2014-01-28 13:45:00 | Last message for now
```

and

```
Table 2: reads
id | message_id | user_id | last_read_timestamp
------------------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 2014-01-20 09:10:00
1 | 2 | 1 | 2014-01-20 09:15:00
1 | 3 | 1 | 2014-01-24 19:25:00
1 | 1 | 2 | 2014-01-28 13:45:00
```

id in Table a relates to message_id in Table 2.

The messages in Table A are updated frequently and the timestamp is updated. So I need to run a query that will return the Table A id of any messages that have been updated SINCE they were read for a particular user_id, for that the user hasn't read (and therefore no corresponding entry appears in Table 2.

So for user_id = 1, message_id 3 has been updated since being read, and message_id 4 is a new message. The result for user_id = 1 would be:

```
Unread
------
3
4
```

I've tried a LEFT JOIN between the tables but just can't seem to get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to retrieve messages unread for a single user, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT messages.id AS unread
FROM
  messages LEFT JOIN (SELECT message_id, MAX(last_read_timestamp) as last_rd
                      FROM reads
                      WHERE user_id = 1
                      GROUP BY message_id) lr
  ON messages.id = lr.message_id
     AND messages.timestamp < lr.last_rd
WHERE
  lr.message_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The Table A id of any messages that have been updated SINCE they were read for a particular user_id; will give below query.(not tested)

```
select * from table1
left join table2 on (table1.id=table2.message_id && table1.timestamp>table2.last_read_timestamp)
where table2.user_id=1;
```